# Instagram API not working: APINotFoundError

Tags: javascript, instagram, instagram-api, instafeedjs

I am using 'instafeed.js' plugin from [here](https://github.com/stevenschobert/instafeed.js) to show my client's Instagram photos on their website. I keep getting an error and have no idea what went wrong. This plugin used to work just fine before.

This is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var feed = new Instafeed({
        get: 'user',
        userId: '2030811713',
        clientId: '2d0b703da7c14a378bc19bc04f120da4',
        accessToken: '***',
        target: 'list-inline',
        limit: '10',
        template: '<li><img src="{{image}}"/></li>',
        resolution: 'standard_resolution',
        after: function() {
            var el = document.getElementById('list-inline');
            if (el.classList)
                el.classList.add('show');
            else
                el.className += ' ' + 'show';
        }
    });
    feed.run();
</script>
```

and this is error I keep getting:

```
/**/ instafeedCache8030560cf189b254.parse({"meta": {"code": 400, "error_type": "APINotFoundError", "error_message": "this user does not exist"}})
```

Please help!

Comment: code is right , are you sure it's a user and also valid id ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The user_id `2030811713` is valid and correct, I can access it using my `access_token`.

My guess is that the user (who's `access_token` you are using in script = `1437995179 @lu.kanemon`) is blocked by user_id `2030811713`

Try using a different `access_token` generated from a different user.

Answer (score 1):

The user id you are providing is wrong, you can check it directly with the api with this link (replace with your access token at the end):
[https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/2030811713/](https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/2030811713/?access_token=PASTE_ACCESS_TOKEN_HERE)

Try searching for the id of the user you want with this link then insert the proper id in the widget. If the user is set as private it will not work.
[https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/search?q=INSERT_USERNAME_HERE](https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/search?q=ENTER_USERNAME_HERE&access_token=PASTE_ACCESS_TOKEN_HERE)

P.S: You should not share your access token openly - just *** it in the example you gave